# $\tan(\theta+i\phi)=\tan(\beta)+i\sec(\beta)$ with conditions

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given $θ,ϕ,β$ are real and $0<β<π$,
$$\tan(\theta+i\phi)=\tan(\beta)+i\sec(\beta)$$
Prove that,
$$e^{2\phi}=\cot(\beta/2)$$
$$\theta=n\pi+\pi/4+\beta/2$$
I have tried expanding the L.H.S. of the given with the exponent form of sin/cos, and also using the addition of angles identity of $\tan$. I took the conjugate of the given and added it, resulting in $$\tan(\beta)=\frac{\tan\theta+\tan\theta\tan^2i\phi}{1-(\tan\theta\tan i\phi)^2}$$

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 3):

$$\tan(\theta+i\phi)=\tan\beta+i\sec\beta$$
thus
$$\tan(\theta-i\phi)=\tan\beta-i\sec\beta$$
we can then arrive at,
$$\tan(2i\phi)=\frac{2i\sec\beta}{1+\tan^2\beta+\sec^2\beta}$$
$$\frac{\tanh2\phi}{-i}=\frac{2i\sec\beta}{1+\tan^2\beta+\sec^2\beta}$$
$$\frac{e^{2\phi}-e^{-2\phi}}{e^{2\phi}+e^{-2\phi}}=\frac{1-tan^2\beta}{1+tan^2\beta}$$
$$e^{2\phi}=\pm\cot(\beta/2)$$
and similarly,
$$\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2\tan\beta}{1-(\tan^2\beta+\sec^2\beta)}$$
$$\tan(2\theta)=-\cot\beta$$
$$\tan(2\theta)=\tan(n\pi+\pi/2+\beta)$$
$$\theta=n\pi/2+\pi/4+\beta/2$$

I think, the question is wrong, it should be $n\pi/2$ instead of $n\pi$.